# Creating Virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a problem setting up a Virtualenv on my web host server (to install python modules later on)

So far I tried this using SSH-access:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar xzf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
~/usr/lib/python2.4 virtualenv-1.5.2/virtualenv.py ~/data/env
```

or

```
~/usr/lib/python2.4 setup.py install
```

I don't get any errors or output and cannot find the ~/data/env-directory that should be created. What is going wrong? Or what is the next step?

Thanks,
Wienel

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the installation path in is PYTHON_PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

$ python couch.py

to check if you running in the Python you think you are.